# Calculate the derivative of the Frobenius norm of matrix logarithm

Tags: matrices, matrix-calculus, positive-definite

Let $h(X)=\|\log(X)\|_{F}^2$ where $X\in\mathbb{S}_{++}^d$ is a $d$ by $d$ symmetric positive definite matrix, $\log$ is the matrix logarithm and $F$ stands for the common Frobenius norm. In section 6.3.2 of [1], the authors calculate the directional derivative of $h$ as follows (note that [1] has a different notation on norms):
$$
D h(X)[Y] = 2\langle X^{-1}\log X, Y\rangle
$$
where $Y$ is any symmetric matrix.

My question is that, how is this calculated? In particular, I know that
$$
\frac{d}{d t} \log(X(t)) = X^{-1}(t) X'(t)
$$
only when $X$ and $X'$ commute, and I'm not sure how to handle the general case.

[1] Bhatia, Rajendra. Positive definite matrices. Princeton university press, 2009.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$
\def\o{{\tt1}}
\def\BR#1{\big[#1\big]}
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\f#1{f\LR{#1}}
\def\ff#1{f'\!\LR{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\big\| #1 \big\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\X{X^{-1}}
\def\L{\log(X)}
\def\LL{\BR{\log(X)}^2}
$The Frobenius product is very useful in Matrix Calculus.
It has these properties
$$\eqalign{
A:B &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n A_{ij}B_{ij} \;=\; \trace{A^TB} \\
I:A &= \trace A \\
A:A &= \frob{A}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
A:B &= B:A \;=\; B^T:A^T \\
\LR{AB}:C &= A:\LR{CB^T} \;=\; B:\LR{A^TC} \\
}$$
[The Matrix Cookbook](https://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ehwolkowi//matrixcookbook.pdf) tells us (on page 12) how to differentiate the trace of a function applied to a matrix argument
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \trace{\f A} \;=\; I:\f A \\
d\phi &= \BR{\ff{A}}^T:dA,\quad\;\; \ff x \equiv \frac{df}{dx} \\
}$$
This follows from the $\sf Daleckii$-$\sf Krein$ Theorem.
It can also be proved by differentiating the Taylor series. For example, here is the calculation for the cubic term
$$\eqalign{
I:d\LR{A^3}
 &= I:\LR{\c{dA}\:AA + A\:\c{dA}\:A + AA\:\c{dA}} \\
 &= \LR{A^2}^T:\c{dA} + \LR{A^2}^T:\c{dA} + \LR{A^2}^T:\c{dA} \\
 &= \LR{3A^2}^T:\c{dA} \\
}$$

Write the current problem using the above notation to obtain
$$\eqalign{
h &= \L:\L \;=\; I:\LL \\
dh &= 2\X\L:dX \\
\grad hX &= 2\X\L \\
}$$
where the symmetry of $X$ allows us to omit all the transposes.